# How to properly generate messages from LibraryLink function?

Tags: librarylink, message-coding

I'm currently using `WolframLibraryData::Message` to generate messages from a library function, like this:

```
Needs["CCompilerDriver`"]
src = "
#include \"WolframLibrary.h\"
DLLEXPORT mint WolframLibrary_getVersion() {return WolframLibraryVersion;}
DLLEXPORT int WolframLibrary_initialize(WolframLibraryData libData) {return 0;}
DLLEXPORT void WolframLibrary_uninitialize(WolframLibraryData libData) {}
  
DLLEXPORT myFunc(WolframLibraryData libData, mint argc, MArgument* args, MArgument result)
{
  libData->Message(\"Here's my message\");
  MArgument_setReal(result,1.1);
  return LIBRARY_NO_ERROR;
}
";
lib = CreateLibrary[src, "mylib"];
myFunc = LibraryFunctionLoad[lib, "myFunc", {}, Real];
```

Now the problem can be seen if `myFunc[]` is called. I get this result:

> LibraryFunction::Here's my message: -- Message text not found -- >>
>
> 1.1

The problem is this `-- Message text not found --` part. Apparently I'm generating the message in a wrong way. So how should I do instead? How do I fill this "message text" to make it look like messages from normal Mathematica functions?

Comment: Good question.  This has been bothering me too.  Theoretically you can call back to the kernel through MathLink to get more flexibility in how to issue messages than what `Message()` allows for.  Setting up a framework to make this easy is going to take a bit of work.  In practical situations the approach I'm taking is to leave this sort of thing (checking errors, issuing user-friendly messages, etc.) to Mathematica code--not C code--as much as possible.

Answer (score 9):

You have not defined any message text in *Mathematica*.

The text you supply in the C code is the message tag, e.g

```
libData->Message("myerror");
```

Then you need to define the actual message content in *Mathematica*:

```
LibraryFunction::myerror = "Here's my message"
```

The relevant documentation page is [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/LibraryLink/ref/callback/Message.html).

Comment: How does this extend to messages with arguments, like e.g. `NIntegrate::inumr`, which looks like `The integrand \`1\` has evaluated to...`? I.e. how do I pass these arguments from the function?

Comment: @Ruslan, I'm not sure. I've never tried to send arguments with the message.

Answer (score 6):

The simple way is what [Simon described in his answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/85393/12).

A more flexible way is described under [Callback Evaluations in the LibraryLink User's Guide](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/LibraryLink/tutorial/LibraryStructure.html#55120353).

Note that in the version 10.0-10.2 documentation there's an error: `getWSTP` should be `getWSLINK`.  You can also use the old (v9) M-prefix function names instead of the WS-prefix ones.  For completeness, I'll reproduce the piece of code from there:

```c
char *msg; // this should contain your message text
int pkt;
MLINK link = libData->getMathLink(libData);
MLPutFunction(link, "EvaluatePacket", 1);
    MLPutFunction(link, "Message", 2);
        MLPutFunction(link, "MessageName", 2);
            MLPutSymbol(link, "MyFunction");
            MLPutString(link, "info");
        MLPutString(link, msg);
libData->processMathLink(link);
pkt = MLNextPacket(link);
if (pkt == RETURNPKT)
    MLNewPacket(link);
```

This will simply evaluate `Message[MyFunction::info, msg]`.  On the Mathematica side you'll want to define something like

```
MyFunction::info = "Message from LibraryLink: ``"
```

You need to `#include "MathLink.h"` for this to work.  This header is located somewhere under `$InstallationDirectory/SystemFiles/Links/MathLink`.

---

**Update:**  I ran into problems with this when [aborting](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/LibraryLink/ref/callback/AbortQ.html) functions.  I don't quite understand what is happening on the MathLink connection during an abort, so for now I simply use `if (libData->AbortQ()) return;` before the above.

Comment: Does this only work with version 10? I get a compilation error `RETURNPKT undeclared`. Could you give a working executable code for Mathematica to make the usage clear?

Comment: @Ruslan It works in v9 too.  You need to `#include "MathLink.h"`.